# How do I fix the ordering in SQL IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The result is coming ordered by code, and do not want to come ordered, want you to come in so I did the query, does anyone know how to solve?

```
SELECT * FROM item where codigo in(14,13,12)
```

result:

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQZqM.png)

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: thanks for replying, however I do not want the sorting is done, and the result of this query is returning ordered.

Comment: As you haven't specified an ORDER BY the result isn't being ordered. It is probably being brought back in the order the rows were found on the table (probably the order they were inserted).

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM item where codigo in(14,13,12) ORDER BY codigo DESC;`. Note that if you don't specify sorting, the server decides and you have no control over it.

Comment: thanks for replying, however my need was the result stayed orderly fashion in which it was consulted.

Comment: If you mean 'oldest row first' or 'newest row first', you need to add a new TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column to your table and ORDER BY it. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `field` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM item
where codigo in(14,13,12)
order by field(codigo, 14, 13, 12);
```

In your case, though, you can just use `order by codigo desc` as well.  I am guessing this is a coincidence.